# How to iterate over a JsonArray in Java (not java 8)

Tags: java, json, loops, parsing, javabeans

I would like to iterate over an array in this Json object:

```
{
  "id": "2234",
  "Messages": [
    {
      "MessageId": 321231239,
      "Text_message": "my text message",
      "date": 1444666348
    },
    {
      "MessageId": 3217437239,
      "Text_message": "my text message 2",
      "date": 1444666348
    }
  ]
}
```

in my code I have:

```
JsonArray messagesJson = jsonObject.getJsonArray("Messages");
```

my imports related to this are:

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
```

Now I want to iterate over this array and extract fields for my bean.
But I don't want to use the for loop with index. I want to use a foreach type of loop. I am working with Java 7.
What I want is something that is more like the Scala way of doing it:

```
messagesJson.map { json => 
    MyBean(
        (json \ "MessageId").getOrElse(""),
        (json \ "text_message").getOrElse(""),
        (json \ "date").getOrElse("")
    )
}
```

Comment: use Gson o jackson, they simplify the iteration and are developed to make easier the life

Comment: What's wrong with `for ( JsonValue val : messageJson ) ...`?

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) says, `JsonArray` extends `List<JsonValue>` so you can simply iterate over `JsonValue`.

```
for(JsonValue value : yourJsonArray){
....
}
```

Comment: How would you turn value into JsonObject?

Comment: you can use getValueType() and check if the result is equal to one of the values of JsonType.ValueType enum. Take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonValue.ValueType.html